# Make Column mandatory based on drop downs in previous columns

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time trying to code with VBA. I have a drop down list in cell A2 and a drop down list in cell B2.

If A2 and B2 are populated (NotBlank?) then the user must enter text into D2 (I would like to make sure the text is longer than 10 characters- hoping no one presses the space bar 10 times) or they can't save (BeforeSave?) else they can save.

I need to make it loop as well. That is, if A3 and B3 are not empty then D3 is mandatory etc. I hope this is clear. Please let me know if I need to explain more.

Here is the code. It works for that one cell, but how do I make it repeat? Do I change the range?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If IsEmpty(Range("A2,B2")) = False Then
        MsgBox "You must enter commentary to validate your ratings"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add code that you have tried out.  SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Have a look at the [Workbook.BeforeSave Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave). Loop through your populated rows and check your criteria (you will find a lot of tutorials for this task). Write something on your own, and if you get stuck or errors come back with your code and a question to it. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Apologies here is the code I have so far. it works for that one cell, but I don't know how to code for subsequent cells .                                                              Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If IsEmpty(Range("A2,B2")) = False Then
    MsgBox "You must enter commentary to validate your ratings"
End If
End Sub

Comment: @Stots Please [edit] your question and add it there. In a comment it is not readable.

Comment: Thank you @PEH. I appreciate the help and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through all used rows and check each cell on its own.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim ws As Worksheet 'specify which sheet here
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long 'find last used row in column A
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow 'loop throug all used rows
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value <> vbNullString And _
           ws.Cells(iRow, "B").Value <> vbNullString And _
           ws.Cells(iRow, "D").Value = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "You must enter commentary to validate your ratings. This file will not be saved!", vbExclamation
            Cancel = True 'do not save
            ws.Cells(iRow, "D").Select 'select missing cell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next iRow

End Sub
```

#### Another idea

This will automatically select all missing cells, and has no loops.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim ConstantsInA As Range
    Set ConstantsInA = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    Dim ConstantsInB As Range
    Set ConstantsInB = ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    Dim EmptyCellsInD As Range
    Set EmptyCellsInD = ws.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    Dim MissingValues As Range
    Set MissingValues = Intersect(ConstantsInA.EntireRow, ConstantsInB.EntireRow, EmptyCellsInD)

    If Not MissingValues Is Nothing Then
        MissingValues.Select 'select missing cells
        MsgBox "You must enter commentary to validate your ratings. This file will not be saved!", vbExclamation
        Cancel = True 'do not save
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For performance reason, would it be better to capture the range in an array and loop through the array to perform the check?

Comment: @Zac Yes, reading/writing arrays is commonly faster than reading/writing cells. • But I think I came up with an even better idea without using loops at all. See my edit.

Comment: Nice!. I was thinking maybe a filter for blank cells but this does it better :)

Comment: @Zac Actually the second one is pretty fast. I was surprised, thought this would be slower.

Comment: plus 1.. I'm gona try it with `Resize`

Comment: @Zac nope my bad `Resize` doesn't work on non-continous ranges.

Comment: Fare enough. I will try this on one of my sheets that has over 600k rows just to test performance enhancements!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! @PEH your answer worked best! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want it to

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim c As Range

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

    If c.Value <> "" And c.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" And c.Offset(0, 3).Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "You must enter commentary in column D" & c.Row & " to validate your ratings before saving"
        Cancel = True

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a lot of calculations that will make this perform really slow. Consider: how can I reduce calculations in my UDF? Your code will do the job but will be very resource hungry and memory intensive. Just a tip for better coding practices